# Eigenfunctions in momentum space of Harmonic osclatior

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

So i need to find the eigenfunctions (in momentum space) of the harmonic oscilator unidimensional.

We know that $(m=\hbar=1)$, in position space, $\psi(x) \propto e^{-x^2} H_n(x)$.

Now, basically the equation in momentum space, for the harmonic oscilator hamiltonian $H = \frac{p^2}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2}$ is equivalent in position space. Therefore, my guess is that

$$\omega_n \propto e^{-p^2} H_n(p)$$

But it seems that we should have a $(-i)^n$ factor, why? Where does it come from?

Comment: The phase factor is obtained if you use a Fourier transform to find the eigenfunctions in momentum space. The Fourier transform can be inverted and you can establish a one-to-one mapping between functions in position and momentum space. If you want this one-to-one property, then you need to include the phase factor. But you could just as well solve the momentum space Hamiltonian for the eigenfunctions and define them without that phase factor. It is just common to keep that phase factor so that the Fourier transform pair property remains intact.